# Recovering texlive distribution from local files

Tags: texlive, texstudio, windows

I had texlive distribution full scheme installed on my windows 11 machine. Yesterday i had to downgrade to Windows 10 inorder to run Aspenplus software. But while doing so, I had to reset my PC. So all the programs got uninstalled except which ship with windows 10, but all my files are intact. So my tex distribution is intact at `C:\texlive\2021`. When i installed `texstudio`, it says no tex distribution found. So how can I use the local texlive packages (which were downloaded before i downgraded to win 10 and still exist at `C:\texlive\2021`) instead of redownloading the full scheme?

Comment: try to update the path variable.

Comment: Thankyou, but I am from a non-IT background, so please can you tell me what to do in layman's terms???

Comment: Use the windows search and search for "environment variables for this account", click on the "Path" entry, click on edit, click on new, and then add C:\texlive\2021\bin\win64 (or win32, browse to the binaries to check the exact path).

Comment: Thankyou very much!!! That worked like a charm! But I want to confirm that can I install tex distribution on any other PC by simply pasting my tex distribution from `C:\texlive\2021\bin\win64` (or win32) in their respective directories and afterwards updating the path variables in them as you said! In other words can I have a portable tex distribution this way???